# STATIC_URL undefined in base Django template

Tags: python, django, static

I have a template, `base.html`, which is used in several other templates for various views. Each of those templates starts with the appropriate `{% extends "base.html" %}`. In the base template, I want to specify a static stylesheet thusly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/base.css"/>
```

However, when it renders most of my templates, the value of `STATIC_URL` is empty, so the attribute is merely `href="/base.css"`, which doesn't load. The variable is properly defined for the template that I have tied to the default login view, `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, but for my own custom views, it's undefined.

I am just trying to get this working in the development environment with `runserver`, so the CSS file is in the static subdirectory of the app.

Here are the relevant bits from my `settings.py`, which are all the defaults:

```
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

In my `urls.py` I also have added:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

#...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can tell this is what you're supposed to do for serving app-specific static files in development, based on [the 1.3 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps this can help:

> If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably
>   not using RequestContext when rendering the template.As a brief
>   refresher, context processors add variables into the contexts of every
>   template. However, context processors require that you use
>   RequestContext when rendering templates. This happens automatically if
>   you're using a generic view, but in views written by hand you'll need
>   to explicitly use RequestContext To see how that works, and to read
>   more details, check out Subclassing Context: RequestContext.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. (The section you quoted is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)) I wasn't calling `render_to_response` with `context_instance = RequestContext(request)`.

Comment: nice! happy to help to you ;)

Comment: If you're using Django 1.3, you don't need to manually pass in the context_instance. The render shortcut will do that for you: return render(request, 'the-template.html', {'foo' : 'bar'})

Comment: danihp says: this text is quoted from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor

Answer (score 15):

You need to add 'django.core.context_processors.static' to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable in settings.py.

Comment: In my case I had not added the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS , even though I was using a class based Generic TemplateView that uses RequestContext, I needed this in my context processors as you explained to have the {{STATIC_URL}} fill in

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add STATIC_URL to to template rendering by passing

```
{'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL}
```

or you can add static context processor see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.core.context_processors.static)

Comment: I have the static context processor, but that alone wasn't working.